# Initializing an custom object that has an array as a property in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, string, swift, class

There was a class created called employee that looks like the following:

```
class Employees: NSObject {

    var name: String
    var employeeRoles: [String]
    var departmentID: Int

    init(name:String, employeeRoles:[String], departmentID:Int){
        self.name = name
        self.employeeRoles = employeeRoles
        self.departmentID = departmentID
    }   
}
```

In the views, there is a text field where you can enter employee roles which are of course strings.  I've attempted to have what information is entered into its respective field, create a new Employees object and print it to the debug console.  However the following line where we attempt to take the strings entered into the view, crashes the program and doesn't provide any further information as to why:

```
let newEmployee = Employees(name:  (employeeFirstNameInputField.text! + " " +  (employeeLastNameInputField.text)!), employeeRoles:  (employeeListingInputField.text as? [String])!, departmentID: 0)

    print(newEmployee.name)
```

Where have I gone wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your text fields are declared as `weak var textField: UITextField!`, then you would create your new employee like this.

```
let name = employeeFirstNameInputField.text + " " +  employeeLastNameInputField.text
let listings = employeeListingInputField.text.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
let newEmployee = Employees(name: name, employeeRoles: listings, departmentID: 0)
```

You need to split the string returned in the listings text field into an array of strings. Each new array element is delimited by a line return.  There are other ways to do this (like calling `split`).

Answer (score 0):

You can't turn a String (`employeeListingInputField.text`) into an array of String through a downcast, so the `as? [String]` will fail and return nil.
You then force unwrap this value with !, which will give you the typical "unexpectedly found nil...` exception.

You have to be careful when using ! As this says "I promise this isn't nil" and you will be punished with an exception if you break your promises.

You have lots of ! here because you are trying to do everything in one line of code. The right thing to do is expand this single line into multiple lines where you check values. This will also enable you to display appropriate messages if, for example, name is blank and so on.

Presuming that having no role is ok, you should check for a 0 length string and use an empty array rather than an array of 1 element which is an empty string. If having no role is not ok then the code below would change to issue an error. You could also use `guard` statements to implement your validation.

```
var roles=[String]()
if employeeListingInputField.text != nil && employeeListingInputField.text!.length > 0 {
    roles.append(employeeListingInputField.text)
 }
```

The use `roles` in your Initializer call

For future reference, the way to convert a single string into a 1 element array of strings is just to say `[myString]`.